# RXJS add observable to existing observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Consider the following DUMMY example of a class that simply holds a list of subjects and a listen method.

```
class X {
  subjects: Subject<any>[] = [new Subject<any>()];
  
  listen(): Observable<any> {
    return merge(...this.subjects).pipe();
  }
}

class Y {
   constructor() {
     new X().listen().subscribe(value => console.log('received', value));
   }
}
```

What if, now, we add a new subject to that list.

```
class X {
  ...
  addSubject(subjectToAdd: Subject<any>): void {
    this.subjects.push(subjectToAdd);
  }
  ...
}
```

if an event is emitted on the subject `subjectToAdd`, the Y class will never log that event since it started listening on the old list. `Y` should not be aware about the internal state of `X`, it says that it wants to listen and should receive any event executed on any subject that is resident in `X`, wether it be there on subscription time or added later.

Note that this is only a dummy example. I just would like to know if there is a way to still call a `listen` method that can add observables to an existing stream.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've done something similar is to use another Subject that is the "add" action. The add action could create a new list from the existing list of subjects.

This isn't your exact scenario, but you may be able to adapt it to your case:

```
  // Action Stream for adding/updating/deleting products
  private productModifiedSubject = new Subject<Action<Product>>();
  productModifiedAction$ = this.productModifiedSubject.asObservable();
```

Above I create a Subject that emits on a create, update, or delete action. (It sounds like you only have add?)

And then it creates a new an array of products. (Yours would create the new array of subjects.)

```
  allProducts$ = merge(
    this.retrievedProducts$,
    this.productModifiedAction$
    ).pipe(
      scan((acc, value) =>
        (value instanceof Array) ? [...value] : this.modifyProducts(acc, value), [] as Product[]),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
```

Also, if you made your `listen` Observable declarative (instead of a method), it would then emit each time the action subject emitted.

If you want to dummy up something on Stackblitz, I could adjust my sample code to be closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a silly idea, though it works (is it then *really* silly?): create a stream of observables and flatten it twice.

```
class X {
  subjects: Subject<any>[] = [new Subject<any>()];

  observables$: Subject<Observable<any>> = new Subject();

  listen(): Observable<any> {
    const arrayOfSubjects = this.observables$.pipe(
      scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []),
      mergeMap((val) => val),
      mergeMap((val) => val) // not a typo
    );

    return merge(arrayOfSubjects);
  }

  addStream(stream: Observable<any>): void {
    this.observables$.next(stream);
  }
}

const x = new X();

x.listen().subscribe(console.log);

x.addStream(of('Hello'));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-q2h9vm?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: It looks like you’re using `scan` to combine emissions into an array, then using the first `mergeMap` to emit them one at a time. I think you could remove the `scan` and first `mergeMap` and get the same result.

Comment: @BizzyBob it seems you are right.